# LOGITECH GHUB LUA: SetMKeyState

Tags: lua, logitech, logitech-gaming-software

I would like to use the SetMKeyState(...) and GetMKeyState(...) functions available in the Logitech LUA scripting api, to write some macros.

I am using Windows 10 and the latest version of Logitech GHUB (I can't use LGS for various reasons). On my keyboard, Logitech G815, it seems that any call to SetMKeyState(...) from a LUA macro does not do anything. While the GetMKeyState(...) seems to correctly return the current MKey state. I have read the docs related to these two functions in the "G-series Lua API V8.45" documentation and it looks like I am using them correctly.

For example, the following LUA script should switch the MKey state between M1/M2/M3 using the G1 key, but actually does not do anything (although the code is executed, as the debug log lines appear):

```
function OnEvent(event, arg)
  if (event == "G_PRESSED" and arg == 1) then
    currentState = GetMKeyState("kb")
    OutputLogMessage("Current MKey state: %d\n", currentState)
    newState = currentState + 1
    if newState == 4 then
      newState = 1
    end
    OutputLogMessage("Setting new MKey state: %d\n", newState )
    SetMKeyState(newState , "kb");
  end
end
```

Am I doing anything wrong here ?

If it is expected that the SetMKeyState(...) function is not supported on the Logitech G815, then which keyboard model would correctly support the SetMKeyState(...) function to change the MKey state ?

Comment: `script should switch the MKey state, but actually does not do anything` - Do you mean M1/2/3 lamp not switched or `GetMKeyState()` returned wrong result?

Comment: Thanks Egor, I really hoped to see you on this one.
If I am in M1 state and use for example SetMKeyState(2, "kb"), then the leds dont change, I dont receive the M_PRESSED event in the following handler events, and the GetMKeyState function returns always the same value 1.

If I press the M2 button by hand, the leds change, and the GetMKeyState returns the new value 2, but I still don't receive the M_PRESSED event in the following OnEvent(...) handler.

Any clue ?

Comment: Looks like a bug in GHUB.

Comment: Thank you, this is enough for me

Answer (score 0):

It's not actually an answer, just a suggestion, but IDK the way to paste the code in comments, so hope you will forgive me :)
There is a reference code in [API doc](https://douile.github.io/logitech-toggle-keys/APIDocs.pdf):

```lua
-- Set the current M Key state to M1 when G1 is pressed
function OnEvent(event, arg)
    if (event == "G_PRESSED" and arg == 1) then
        SetMkeyState(1);
    end
end
```

If I were you I'd get started from the check if it works or not as it is, without any change.

Then, step by step:

- add debug messages;
- recheck;
- try to set it to 2 instead of 1;
- try to set it to 3;
- try to read and print current state, before and after the operation, considering this remark from API doc: *"Calling GetMKeyState immediately afterwards, will likely return the previous state. Use the OnEvent handler to determine when the operation has completed."*

Comment: I have already done that, and it seems to me from the debug output that the code proceeds as intended. It is just the SetMKeyState(...) function that seems to not change the MKey state. There are leds over the M keys, so I can see which state it is, and I have different configurations for the G buttons when the MKey state changes, and not the leds nor the buttons change when I invoke the SetMKeyState(...). So I was asking for help to understand if it was an issue in the code, or my keyboard broken, or a known behavior.